# How to separate one cell element into two separate cell elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array which looks like this:

```
abc = {[1,0,1,0];[1,1,0,1];[1,1,1,0]};
```

I want to separate each cell element into two groups like this:

```
abc(:,2) = {[1,0];[1,1];[1,1]};
abc(:,3) = {[1,0];[0,1];[1,0]};
```

I tried using this statement to do it:

```
abc(:,2:3) = cellfun(@(x) mat2cell(x,[1],[2,2]),abc(:,1),'uni',0);
```

But this statement gives the following error:

> Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

When I try to assign it to `abc(:,2)` instead of `abc(:,2:3)`, I get the result but as a cell within a cell which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign directly to columns `2:3` of `abc` because the output of `cellfun` doesn't match the expected dimension. It is `3 x 1` while `abc(:,2;3)` is `3 x 2`. You can use call to `cat` to make it work though.

```
abc = {[1,0,1,0];[1,1,0,1];[1,1,1,0]};

tmp = cellfun(@(x) mat2cell(x,[1],[2,2]),abc(:,1),'uni',0);
abc(:,2:3) = cat(1, tmp{:});

%// [1x4 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
%// [1x4 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
%// [1x4 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

An alternative that doesn't use `cellfun` could be.

```
abc = {[1,0,1,0];[1,1,0,1];[1,1,1,0]};

abc(:,2:3) = mat2cell(cat(1, abc{:}), ones(1,size(abc,1)), [2 2]);
```

Comment: I guess I will have to go with the first option because abc is just a column from another cell which i used for simplicity. I can not use `abc(:,2){:}` right? I will have to use a temp variable any ways! But thanks for both the ways!

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil You could just simply do `abc{:,2}`

Comment: Now i have perfectly understood the difference between () and {} for a cell! Thanks